# JavaFX 8 TableView: If the FixedCellSize property is being used, a column cannot be hidden

Tags: javafx, tableview, javafx-8, tablecolumn

When I paint the background of a column and then I fixed the size of a cell, this happens when I hidden a column:
[image]

If I comment this line: "table.setFixedCellSize(24)" works correctly:
[image]

But I need fix the size of a cell... ¿Does this error have any solutions?

Many thanks to all and sorry for my poor English.

You can run my example:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.CheckBox;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Test extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(final Stage stage) {

        // Create Items
        final ObservableList<Person> data = 
        FXCollections.observableArrayList(new Person("Ruben", "Martin"),
        new Person("Ruben", "Martin"), new Person("Ruben", "Martin"));

        // Create columns
        final TableColumn<Person, String> firstNameCol = 
        new TableColumn<>("First Name");
        firstNameCol.setCellValueFactory(
        new PropertyValueFactory<>("firstName"));

        final TableColumn<Person, String> lastNameCol = 
        new TableColumn<>("Last Name");
        lastNameCol.setCellValueFactory(
        new PropertyValueFactory<>("lastName"));

        // Create Table
        final TableView<Person> table = new TableView<>();
        table.setFixedCellSize(24);
        table.setItems(data);
        table.getColumns().addAll(firstNameCol, lastNameCol);

        // Create CheckBox
        final CheckBox checkLastName = new CheckBox();
        checkLastName.setText("Last Name");
        checkLastName.setSelected(true);
        lastNameCol.setStyle("-fx-background-color:yellow");
        lastNameCol.visibleProperty().
        bindBidirectional(checkLastName.selectedProperty());

        final VBox vbox = new VBox();
        vbox.setSpacing(5);
        vbox.setPadding(new Insets(10, 0, 0, 10));
        vbox.getChildren().addAll(table, checkLastName);

        final Scene scene = new Scene(new Group());
        stage.setWidth(450);
        stage.setHeight(550);
        ((Group) scene.getRoot()).getChildren().addAll(vbox);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    public static class Person {

        private final SimpleStringProperty firstName;
        private final SimpleStringProperty lastName;

        private Person(final String fName, final String lName) {
            this.firstName = new SimpleStringProperty(fName);
            this.lastName = new SimpleStringProperty(lName);
        }

        public String getFirstName() {
            return this.firstName.get();
        }

        public void setFirstName(final String fName) {
            this.firstName.set(fName);
        }

        public String getLastName() {
            return this.lastName.get();
        }

        public void setLastName(final String fName) {
            this.lastName.set(fName);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This seems to be a bug in JavaFX: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8156090  
Unfortunately, as it does not exist in Java 9 (which is not yet released), it seems it was deemed unworthy of a fix.

Comment: I sort of see where this comes from. In general in JavaFX, a node that is not `visible` still occupies space in the scene graph, assuming it is `managed`. So it (sort of) makes sense that a column that is not visible takes up the same amount of space whether it is visible or not. If the cell size is not fixed,  then a cells in a column that is not visible would not display anything, so their preferred width would be 0. OTOH, if the cell size is fixed, it fixes the width of the column. It's probably not the desired behavior, but I see how it arises.

Answer (score 0):

Probably this is a workaround but it works:

```
StringBinding sb = Bindings.when(lastNameCol.visibleProperty())
                .then("-fx-background-color:yellow")
                .otherwise("");
        lastNameCol.styleProperty().bind(sb);
```